# Why do parallel memory chips in a DIP package have a disorganized pin arrangement?

Tags: signal, eeprom, ram, pinout

I'm looking at datasheet for old RAM's and EEPROMS, and one in particular I'm using is part AT28C256. Why is it that the order of the address lines do not correspond with the actual pin number. An example of mis-alignment is that on a AT28C256, the first 10 pins are labeled A14, A12, A7, A6, A5, A4, A3, A2, A1, and A0. Why don't the engineers of the chip make it so they can be labelled as A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, and A9? and just saying to label the lines yourself isn't an answer because some chips use a special timing where if you write data to the first n bytes in a certain period of time, the write supposedly executes faster (at least thats what the AT28C256 datasheet claims).

Also, Why are the control signals (such as the OE and CE in AT28C256) assigned to the middle pins of the chip instead of the outer pins?

I ask this because I'm having a hard time routing everything without resorting to multiple extra long jumpers (or double-sided board which I'm not ready for yet).

Comment: Some of it is history. The 28256 used to be the 27256 EPROM, and that started out as the 2708 EPROM, in a 24 pin package. Then the 2716 added one more address pin (A10) on whatever pin was available (probably the -5V pin which was no longer needed) and it grew from there...

Answer (score 4):

First version of chip had address lines A0-A7 to the "left" and A8-A10 to the "right" (as you look into pinput in the datasheet). For compatibility reasons pins are being added from its "pin starting side" of the chip: if you ever programmed EEPROMs you know you always insert chips aligned with their "back", and then you only need to tell programmer the size of chip and it will automatically know where power pin is and how many addresses it has. That's why A0-A7 are contiguous, and then pin numbers start jumping at the "left" side of pinout.

Comment: The OP should look at the D2758 and D2716 datasheets, which have been the grandfathers of all EPROM and FlashROMs. (D2708 has an odd pinout with three supply voltages.)